# how to get base_64 string of file upload using jquery with browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv

hi I can anyone help me I need to get just the base_64 code of the csv file I want to upload

this is my code with filter of csv

```
function readCSV(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        var filename = input.files[0].name;
        var ext = filename.split('.').pop();

        if(input.files[0].type == "text/csv" || ext == "csv" || ext == "xls"){
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
            var base_64 = e.target.result;
            console.log(base_64);

            var array = new Uint8Array(100);
                array[42] = 10;
                $('#file_name').html(input.files[0].name);
                $('#filename').val(input.files[0].name);
                $('#content').val(base_64);

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }else{
            $('#file_name').html('<span style="color:red; font-size:11px"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Invalid File Please try again!</span>');
        }
    }
}
```

in my logcat when I `console.log(base_64)`

the result from Google Chrome was

```
data:base64,UHJvZHVjdCBOYW1lL....(rest of base_64 string)
```

I just need to have the base_64 string

so I came out with this solution

`//replace function
content.replace('data:;base64,', '');`

i just remove the `data:base64,` in the string

but when i tried in firefox the result was

`data:application/octet-stream;base64,UHJvZHVjdCBOYW1lL....(rest of base_64 string)`

differ from the first result so my replace function won't work

but I don't want to add another replace function because my worries is if browser push an update maybe the `data:base64` will be `1.0.data:base64` or `v.1.data:base64` so whenever the string changes my system will fail.

could anyone help me please. I just need to get the base_64 string, Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you do `console.log(({}).toString.call(base_64)` and `console.log(typeof base_64)`?

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago wait i'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the string using a comma as a delimiter, and then grab the last element from the newly created array which will represent your base64 data:

```
//split into ['data:application/octet-stream;base64', 'UHJvZHVjdCBOYW1lL']
var arr = content.split(',');
var base64 = arr[arr.length-1];
```

As mentioned by bergi, the base64 data is [defined to appear](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397#section-3) after the last comma

Comment: sir is this sure that the base_64 string always on last? if yes this would do. thanks

Comment: Yes, the base64 string is always last. Here is the link provided by bergi: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397#section-3

Answer (score 1):

[Data URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Url) do have a [well-defined syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397#section-3), so radical changes like the ones you have depicted are unlikely.

```
var base_64 = this.result.replace(/^data:.*?;base64,/, "");
```

will do the job.

Comment: oh.. so the one changes is the mediatype ? could you explain the regex inside replace. pls. thanks

Comment: It's a simple [begin anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), followed by `data:`, followed by [multiple](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [anything](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), followed by `base64,`. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Actually, not even the mediatype should change. It [is specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#readAsDataURL) to depend on the [file's `.type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-type) - the whose detectability seems to differ between browsers. Chrome falls back to text (which can be omitted from the data-url), FireFox defaults to `octet-stream`.